# Laravel guzzel result implement to blade laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, guzzle

i have problem while **displaying json data in laravel blade**, i request data using guzzel and this is my code:

```
public function index(){
  $client = new Client();
  $schedules = $client->get('45.112.125.25:5500/md_data/schedules/', [
      'query' => [
          'vCategory' => '129',
          'vStartDate' => '2017-07-01',
          'vEndDate' => '2017-09-31',
          'vReadKey' => 850601165,
          'vRows' => 10,
          'vOffset' => 0
      ]
  ]);
  // return $schedules->getBody();
  return view('trainingList')->with('schedules', $schedules->getBody());
 }
```

this result :

```
[{"f_training_schedule_id":324,"f_training_category_id":129,"f_training_category":"Workshop Business","f_city_id":216,"f_city_name":"Kota Jakarta Selatan","f_training_schedule_startdate":"2017-08-11T17:00:00.000Z","f_training_schedule_enddate":"2017-08-12T17:00:00.000Z","f_training_schedule_batch":1,"f_training_schedule_trainer":58,"f_training_schedule_address":"<!--StartFragment-->JL TB Simatupang, Cilandak, RT.3/RW.3, Cilandak Tim., Ps. Minggu<!--EndFragment-->\r\n\r\n<br>"}]
```

how to get specific data from the above results.

for example I want to get value from f_training_schedule_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
return view('trainingList')->with('schedules', json_decode($schedules->getBody(), true));
```

In your blade template

```
$schedules[0]['f_training_schedule_id'];
```

Foreach:

```
@foreach ($schedules as $schedule)
    <p>{{ $schedule['f_training_schedule_id'] }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: how to get with foreach ?